# Perfect Adaptation to Surface

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I want to model a implant for 3D printing in STL format.

I need to adapt only part of my object (implant) to the surface and also maintain the thickness of the object at 1 mm every where. I have tried several methods and noting is working. [image: Implant]

Top picture is the basic implant designed i made.

[image: Mandible]

This is the Mandible from the CBCT of the patient. In STL format.

[image: Adaptation]

I want the inner surface of the implant to warp or adjust in to the surface of the mandible. Also that part need to be in 1 mm thickness.

Can some one please tell me the workflow that i should follow in this case ? and get the surface well adapted to the complex geometry while maintaining the thickness.

After trying method suggested by Lemon

enter image description here
[image]

Comment: Shrinkwrap modifier can use a vertex group, so you can choose the part that will "exactly" follow the mandible surface (eventually, subdivide your mesh before doing that: subdivision modifier with "simple" option). Also can consider solidify modifier in order to obtain 1mm thickness.

Comment: You should add that as an answer @lemon

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart I tried it and the implant looks weird on the affected region. I first apply shirinkwrap and then did the solidify and try it the other way around too. :-(

Comment: We can't help without a file or more screenshots.

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart i can send the both the stl file and the implant i would like to have the surface adapted. How can i send the file ?

Comment: @ArthurBlaquart i have uploaded the files to https://we.tl/t-z6jmJPBWSX if you would like to have a look and help me if possible

Comment: Manjula, you should solidify first if your model has no thickness (and apply it). Now create a vertex group for the vertices of the inner part and use shrinkwrap with this group (PS: I can't upload your files as I currently have a very low and unstable internet connection).

Comment: @lemon Yes i already tried that way too. I applied solidify and then selected the only the inner surface vertexes and created a vertex group and then applied the shrinkwrap. However still that part of the implant looks weird..... I am very new to blender and i think i might be missing some critical part of this process.